# Grails 3.0.9 <g:layoutHead /> includes content into <body> tag instead of <head>

Tags: java, grails

It's a layout main.gsp

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <g:layoutHead />
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody />
    </body>
    </html>
```

It's a page template index.gsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>
<body>
index.gsp
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>[]



    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="layout" content="main">




index.gsp


</body>
</html>
```

It's a controller that calls render:

```
def indexPage(){
        render view: "/index", model: [page: "index"]
    }
```

I checked the documentation several times but didn't find errors in my code. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: It's working in 2.4.4, not sure what has changed in regards to this. Also, do you mean 'index.gsp`?

Comment: I cope example from documentation for 3.x.
you are right, i meant index.gsp, fixed.